# Particular string split in R

Tags: string, r

I'd like to split a text string in R but I want to take some aspects into consideration. For instance, if the string has a dot `.` or a `!`, I want my function to take them as elements of my split list. Below an example of what I want to get.

```
  mytext="Caracas. Montevideo! Chicago."  
  split= "Caracas", "." ,"Montevideo", "!", "Chicago", "."
```

My current approach consists in replacing previously with the built-in R function `gsub` the "." by " . " and then I use strsplit function as well.

```
  mytext=gsub("\\."," .",mytext)
  mytext=gsub("\\!"," !",mytext)
  unlist(strsplit(mytext,split=' '))
```

So, my question is: is there another way of implementing this by configuring the parameters for the `strsplit` function or another approach you coonsider could be more efficient.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look-ahead is what you're looking for here:

```
strsplit(mytext, split = "(?=(\\.|!))", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "Caracas"     "."           " Montevideo" "!"           " Chicago"    "."
```

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that the `perl` flag is critical for look aheads in R

Answer (score 1):

eddi's solution doesn't split the whitespaces. Try this:

```
> regmatches(mytext, gregexpr(text=mytext, pattern="(?=[\\.\\!])|(?:\\s)", perl=T), invert=T)
[[1]]
[1] "Caracas"    "."          "Montevideo" "!"          "Chicago"    "."
```